# Winforms ComboBox is adding a line item at runtime

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

UPDATED BELOW

```
var billers = user.FindBillers();
billers.Insert(0, new user { strLName = "- -" });
billers.Insert(1, new user { strLName = "Provider Default" });


cboBillingProvdr.DataSource = null;
cboBillingProvdr.DataSource = billers;
cboBillingProvdr.DisplayMember = "FullName";
cboBillingProvdr.ValueMember = "ID";


if (Currentuser.billerid == -1)
    cboBillingProvdr.SelectedIndex = 1;
else if (CurrentUser.billerid > 0)
    cboBillingProvdr.SelectedValue = CurrentUser.billerid ;
else
    cboBillingProvdr.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

This is how the `ComboBox` displays on the `Form` if there is any biller value (>0) coming from the database:

```
 - -
 Provider Default
 --
 Provider 1
 Provider 2
 Provider 3
```

UPDATE: I did not see anywhere in user.findbillers adding that " -- ". But on the same form this below code is doing that I believe. When I comment it, everything seems to work.

```
    var Physicians= user.FindBillers();
    cboPhysician.DataSource = null;
    Physicians.Insert(0, new user { strFName = "--" });
    Physician.DataSource = Physicians;
    Physician.DisplayMember = "FullName";
```

The on load of the form and subsequent clicks call these but I don't know why one should affect the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code in this scope is not adding the "--" item, you need to check your user.FindBillers() method (or post it here as an edit). There should be a line of code similar to:

```cs
/* assuming the returned collection's name is 'findBillers' */
findBillers.Insert(0, new user { "--" });
/* or */
findBillers.Add(new user { "--" });
```

That way, your posted list is returned as a result like:

```
--
Provider 1
Provider 2
Provider 3
```

And then, with your two lines of code

```
billers.Insert(0, new user { strLName = "- -" });
billers.Insert(1, new user { strLName = "Provider Default" });
```

You end with this list

```
- - (Inserted at 0)
Provider Default (Inserted at 1)
--
Provider 1
Provider 2
Provider 3
```

So, you have to either

a) Comment / remove the line inside user.FindBillers()

b) Comment / remove your two inserts to billers and add the `Provider Default` inside user.FindBillers()

**EDIT:**  You can post the code of user.FindBillers() and I'll update my answer.

Comment: I was wondering that. Makes sense. I'll look for the "--" in user.

Comment: So there is user.FindBillers on the same form and its adding a "--" to a different combobox which seems to be the problem! I never thought that should affect this billing combo box!

Comment: Beware `side effect`

Comment: I added the code above that's affecting this combo. They are on the same form, different tabs. Nothing in user class itself.

Comment: @Ree Your problem is within the `user` class (in Visual Studio right-click on `FindBillers()` and select `Go To Definition` (or highlight the code and click `F12`)

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED. I added another method, FindBillers1() in the user class and called that to populate the 2nd combo and it worked as crazy as that sounds. There is no difference between FindBillers and FindBillers1 except the name.